# How to use *ngFor with a list that I got from service?

Tags: angular

A user selects a value from a list:

```
<form [formGroup]="selectForm">
<select formControlName="fcName"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
<option *ngFor='let options of furnitureList' [value]="options.color">{{options.color}}</option>
    </select>
```

I then take what value was chosen into the next select:

```
<select formControlName="fcName2"
<option *ngFor='let options of availableList' [value]="options.location">{{options.location}}</option>
</select>
```

My component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ApiService.getFurnitureList().subscribe(data => {this.furnitureList = data;});
}

onChange($x: any){
    this.ApiService.getAvailableListByFurniture($x.target.value).subscribe(data => {
      this.availableList = data;
    });
    }
```

When I console log `this.availableList` I get a response with the correct values inside it. HOWEVER, when I do `*ngFor="let option of availableList"` I get the correct number of objects but they are all undefined. Like so:

[image]

What's happening?

Comment: can you log `this.availableList` ? It looks like each item does not have a `location` attribute.

Comment: `this.availableList` returns the data that it should - [{id: 1, location: "London"}, {id: 2, location: "USA"}]

Comment: you must be missing something else then. Can you add a screenshot of the console.log in your question ?

Comment: @Random on mobile, can't do that for the time being. But I assure you the data in availableList is correct, I checked multiple times.

Comment: as I said, your code looks pretty simple, so there must be something you asume right which is wrong. The HTML says "every `options` does not a any attribute called `location`", but the ngFor sees the right number of items. So there must be a nested object, or a typo somewhere...

Comment: When instead of `{{options.location}}` I write just `{{options}}` I get `[object Object]`, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. I was editing the backend earlier today and appearently instead of returning "Location", I was returning "location". That caused angular to be very confused it seems.

Comment: So the assumption that the backend returned the data it should was wrong :) Nice you noticed it.